# solution of linear congruence system

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Solve
\begin{cases}
\;\,2x \quad\quad \equiv 1 \ \pmod 5 \\
(5x+2) \equiv 2 \pmod{18}
\end{cases}

Now I have read about the Chinese Remainder Theorem, which is particularily helpful in solving systems of linear congruence, but in this notice that the moduli are not relatively prime (pairwise). So, I cannot apply the theorem. In fact this leads me to a general question: If we are given as system:

$$a_1x\equiv b_1\pmod {n_1}\\ a_2x\equiv b_2\pmod {n_2} \\a_3x\equiv b_3\pmod {n_3}\\ a_4x\equiv b_4\pmod {n_4} \\...\\ a_rx\equiv b_r\pmod {n_r}$$

where the moduli are not pairwise relatively prime. How do we go about solving this system and what are the conditions that determine the solvability of the system.

Answer (score 1):

$2x \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$

$5x+2 \equiv 2 \pmod{18}$

You can solve this using some modified techniques of regular algebra.

For example if $2x=1$, makes you want to divide by 2, but how do you do that modulo 5? You multiply by the multiplicative inverse of 2 modulo 5. Given $2x\equiv 1$, multiply both sides by 3, $6x\equiv 3 \pmod{5}$. But $6\equiv 1 \pmod{5}$. So the multiplication gives you $x\equiv 3 \pmod{5}$.

Something similar applies to the second equation.

$5x+2 \equiv 2 \pmod{18}$

Subtract 2 from both sides: $5x \equiv 0 \pmod{18}$.

Dividing by 5 is multiplying by 11 in modulo 18.

So ultimately, the second equation becomes $x\equiv 0 \pmod{18}$.

So now we have two congruence relations:

$x \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$

$x \equiv 0 \pmod{18}$.

Now you can use the chinese remainder theorem. The definitions lead you to some possible answers.

$x \equiv 3 \pmod{5} \implies x=5p+3$.

Plug that in to x on the left of the second congruence:

$5p+3=0 \pmod{18}$

$5p \equiv 15 \pmod{18}$. So multiply by 11:

$p \equiv 3 \pmod{18}\implies p=18q+3 $

So $x=90q+18 \implies x \equiv 18 \pmod{90}$

You can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find multiplicative inverses.
[Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) helps get the inverses and works to prove the chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a congruence in the form of $x \equiv b \ (\bmod{n})$
with $n=p_1^{r_1} \cdots p_k^{r_k}$ such that $p_1,...,p_k$ are different prime numbers and $r_1,...r_k \ge1$, you can split you congruence in the following way: 
$$
x \equiv b \ (\bmod{n}) \iff  
\begin{cases}
x \equiv b \ (\bmod p_1^{r_1})\\
\dots &  \\
x \equiv b \ (\bmod p_k^{r_k})
\end{cases}
$$
in your question: 
$$
\begin{cases}
2x \equiv 1 \ (\bmod 5)\\
5x \equiv 0 \ (\bmod 18)
\end{cases} \iff
\begin{cases}
x \equiv 3 \ (\bmod 5)\\
5x \equiv 0 \ (\bmod 9)\\
5x \equiv 0 \ (\bmod 2)
\end{cases} \iff
\begin{cases}
x \equiv 3 \ (\bmod 5)\\
x \equiv 0 \ (\bmod 9)\\
x \equiv 0 \ (\bmod 2)
\end{cases}
$$
Now you can apply the Chinese-Remainder-Theorem.

Comment: How can I continue with the solution with what you have just proposed?

Comment: @fred do you know how to use the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: I'm actually just starting to see it and I don't know it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special theorems to do this problem because the second equation says we are looking for $5x$ to be a multiple of $18$. But $5$ and $18$ are relatively prime so we must have $x$ be a multiple of $18$.

We first try $18$ and we not that $2*18=36$ which is congruent to $1$ mod $5$.

Any multiple of $18$ solves the second equation and $18+5k$ solves the first equation. Since $18+5k$ must be a multiple of $18$ to satisfy the second equation, we must have that $k$ is a multiple of $18$.

Therefore, the general solution is $18+5(18m)=18 + 90m=18(1+5m)$.

Comment: by "m" you mean mod?

Comment: @fred m can be any integer. I am saying $18,108, 198,,,$ solves this.

Comment: sorry I mean the "m"

Answer (score 0):

$2$ is relatively prime to $5$ so $2$ will have a multiplicative inverse $\pmod 5$.  [That is to say, there will exist a distinct value $a$ (in $\mathbb Z_5$) so that $2a \equiv 1 \pmod 5$]

If you can figure out what $a$, we will use the notation $2^{-1}_5$, then we can do:

$2x\equiv 1 \pmod 5 \implies$

$2x \cdot 2_5^{-1} \equiv 1\cdot 2_5^{-1} \pmod 5\implies$

$x \equiv 2_5^{-1} \pmod 5$

And as $5$ is relatively prime to $18$ so $5$ will have a multiplicative inverse $\pmod{18}$.  That is there exist a unique value (of $\mathbb Z_{18}$) which we can call $b$ or $5_{18}^{-1}$ so that $5b \equiv 1 \pmod {18}$.

If you can figure out what $b$ (or $5_{18}^{-1}$) is, then we can do:

$5x + 2 \equiv 2 \pmod {18}\implies$

$5x \equiv 0 \pmod {18}\implies$

$5x\cdot 5_{18}^{-1} \equiv 0\cdot 5_{18}^{-1}\implies$

$x \equiv 0 \pmod {18}$.

So now just use the CRT on

$x\equiv 2_{5}^{-1} \pmod 5$ and

$x\equiv 0 \pmod {18}$.

What is $2_{5}^{-1}$?

> $2a \equiv 1 \pmod 5\implies$
>  That $2a = 1 + 5k$ for some irrelevent integer $k$ that we don't care about $\implies$
>  $2a = 6 + 5(k-1)\implies $
>  $a = 3 + 5\cdot\frac {k-1}2 \implies$
>  $\frac {k-1}2$ must be an integer.  That is $k$ is odd.  But we don't care *anything* about $k$ or $\frac {k-1}2$    and that implies
>  $a \equiv 3 \pmod 5$.
>  So $2_5^{-18}$ is $3$.
>  .... And $2 \cdot 3 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$.